# Interesting sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, prime-numbers

Let a sequence $x_n$ defined through the next relations:$x_n = 6x_{n-1}+22n$, for $n > 0$ and $x_0 = 1$. Find the general form of $x_n$ and explain if $x_{100}$ is a prime number. 
My solution must use Z transformation, but every time I try to solve it I obtain a wrong solution. I think the problem is that I don't know how to compute the function $A$ such that $X(z) - 6X(z)*\frac{1}{z}=A(z)$ (I applied Laplace transformation) and more precisely, how to compute $a_n$ such that $A(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^{-n}$. I don't understand what are the $a_n$ values in this situation. Some advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x_n$ is even (so not prime) for $n>0$

Comment: Yeah, I know, parameters are not the best in this situation. We can use $x_n = ax_{n-1}+bn$ instead. My real problem is that the recurrence isn't linear.

Comment: It's $x_n=8x_{n-1}-13x_{n-2}+6x_{n-3}$

Comment: Thank you. Your idea helped me to solve the sequence using Z transformation. I used $x_n-7x_{n-1} + 6x_{n-2}=22$ and to create the "environment" I need.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_n=\frac{x_n}{6^n}$, then $u_{n+1}=u_n+\frac{22n}{6^n}$ so that
$$ u_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{22k}{6^k} $$
Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$ then $f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}kx^{k-1}=\frac{-nx^{n-1}(1-x)+1-x^n}{(1-x)^2}$ so that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k}{6^k}=\frac{1}{6}f'\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)=\frac{6}{25}\left(1-\frac{5n+1}{6^n}\right) $$
Finally $x_n=6^nu_n=6^n+\frac{132}{25}(6^n-5n-1)$. Moreover $x_{100}$ is not prime because $x_100=2(3x_{99}+11n)$ is even and $x_{100}>2$. (I hope there is no error of calculus)

Comment: I think $x_n=\frac{157}{25}6^n-\frac{\color{red}{22}}5n-\frac{132}{25}$

Comment: I think for your formula $x_1 = 6$, but if I use the recurrence I have $x_1 = 28$. Probably just a calculus error. However, your solution is very beautiful :)